# Windows 10: change/disable Ctrl+` hotkey

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I occasionally need to press both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> keys at the same time, but for some reason it switches tasks. Is there any way to change this behavior on Windows 10?

Comment: `ctrl`+`\`` is not a standard [windows 10 shortcut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Are you trying to switch between programs? If so use Alt+Tab (it's always been Alt+Tab...) I don't think there is a way to change your hot keys the way you are describing

Comment: Weird, why does it keep switching between my browser and file explorer then? I don't want it to have any special functionality other than separate ctrl and `.